# pulse 'cannot find repositories containing artifacts'

Tags: java, gwt, osgi, myeclipse

i have been struggling with installing google plugin in myeclipse config center for long and i have managed to overcome a number of issues as described below. i am using myeclipse 10.7.1 with base indigo 3.7.2.
i downloaded this zip com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.3.7.update.site_3.6.0 and added it to available software sites.
i disabled firewall and i dont have any antivirus installed, i have no proxy server and eclipse has no problem accessing sites as far as i can see because i checked the 'contact all sites...' option other wise it would fail to install and tell me it did not find 'org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0'.
i added the line
`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
to eclipse.ini, other wise it would fail to install and tell me it could not find osgi.bundle blah blah blah.
i have been testing with both plain indigo 3.7 and myeclipse.
however, at this stage, indigo gave up all its errors and gwt is happily sitting in the toolbar.
but for some reason myeclipse goes through all the steps and just at the end it tells me it `An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=com.poweredbypulse.profile-0-rb-5513151-1406359175233, phase=com.genuitec.pulse2.client.common.download.PulseCollect, operand=, action=).
  Could not find repositories containing the following artifacts: [osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.6.0.v20110608-1400, osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.6.1.v20110720-0100]`

 and that simply marks the end of my struggle and i have to start all over looking endlessly for solution.
my local plugin repository contains plugins,features,artifacts.jar and content.jar.
i am not very familiar with osgi. however when i attempted to view its console logs, i saw 10 lines like
   `INFO: loading artifacts for http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/products/pulse/mirrors in 722 ms
    aug 15,2014 9:48:45 am com.genuitec.pulse2.client.common.p2.p2bridge cacheRepositories`
the last of them was:
  `INFO: loading artifacts for http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/jdks in 1830 ms
    [Fatal Error]:11749:66: Premature end of file.
    aug 15,2014 9:48:45 am com.genuitec.pulse2.client.common.p2.p2bridge processOperands`
is there somebody out there who understands this issue as i have crawled the web for several hours and i have not managed to get anything to proceed from here and all my boss says is "i trust you enough to finish it within the next 24 hours"

NB. editing specific update sites is straightforward in base eclipse but i have not seen such an option in myeclipse config center i.e the list of sites in the work with combobox of eclipse are invisible ,atleast to me, in myeclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have the answer
i have tried to run the install again, this time paying more attention to the osgi console logs and i have captured more lines:

`WARNING: unable to load repository http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/eclipse/updates/3.7
WARNING: unable to load repository http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/releases/indigo`

when i try to access the second url from mybrowser
`403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/releases/indigo/ on this server
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at eclipse.poweredbypulse.com Port 80`

same for the second url which i have just tried.
The problem i think is the failure to access these two update sites.

Comment: That permission message is often returned when trying to access an eclipse update site outside of eclipse. You might have better luck with the latest release of MyEclipse (2014 or 2015), as the configuration center is no longer there with the installation structure being more like standard eclipse. Your MyEclipse license is time based, not release based, so it will work for later releases, if it is still valid.